# Why does Spring defer to close a Hibernate session when use Hibernate 3

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm

**Background**:

I am working on upgrading **Hibernate 3** used in our product to **Hibernate 4**. The Spring version we are using is **Spring 3.2** and our code heavily uses Spring 3.2's **HibernateTemplate**, which is not supported in the package **org.springframework.orm.hibernate4** any more. As the first step, my task is to write a customized version of HibernateTemplate which uses SessionFactory to get a session and remove all the dependencies of Hibernate 3.

**Problems**:

When I read the source code of Spring 3.2, I notice that many APIs in **org.springframework.orm.hibernate3** are removed in **org.springframework.orm.hibernate4**. One of the cases is the **closeSessionOrRegisterDeferredClose** method in **SessionFactoryUtils** of **org.springframework.orm.hibernate3** package.

```
/**
 * Close the given Session or register it for deferred close.
 * @param session the Hibernate Session to close
 * @param sessionFactory Hibernate SessionFactory that the Session was created with
 * (may be {@code null})
 * @see #initDeferredClose
 * @see #processDeferredClose
 */
static void closeSessionOrRegisterDeferredClose(Session session, SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    Map<SessionFactory, Set<Session>> holderMap = deferredCloseHolder.get();
    if (holderMap != null && sessionFactory != null && holderMap.containsKey(sessionFactory)) {
        logger.debug("Registering Hibernate Session for deferred close");
        // Switch Session to FlushMode.MANUAL for remaining lifetime.
        session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);
        Set<Session> sessions = holderMap.get(sessionFactory);
        sessions.add(session);
    }
    else {
        closeSession(session);
    }
}
```

This method is invoked by the doExecute method of **HibernateTemplate** class (last line of code)

```
/**
 * Execute the action specified by the given action object within a Session.
 * @param action callback object that specifies the Hibernate action
 * @param enforceNewSession whether to enforce a new Session for this template
 * even if there is a pre-bound transactional Session
 * @param enforceNativeSession whether to enforce exposure of the native
 * Hibernate Session to callback code
 * @return a result object returned by the action, or {@code null}
 * @throws org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException in case of Hibernate errors
 */
protected <T> T doExecute(HibernateCallback<T> action, boolean enforceNewSession, boolean enforceNativeSession)
        throws DataAccessException {

    Assert.notNull(action, "Callback object must not be null");

    Session session = (enforceNewSession ?
            SessionFactoryUtils.getNewSession(getSessionFactory(), getEntityInterceptor()) : getSession());
    boolean existingTransaction = (!enforceNewSession &&
            (!isAllowCreate() || SessionFactoryUtils.isSessionTransactional(session, getSessionFactory())));
    if (existingTransaction) {
        logger.debug("Found thread-bound Session for HibernateTemplate");
    }

    FlushMode previousFlushMode = null;
    try {
        previousFlushMode = applyFlushMode(session, existingTransaction);
        enableFilters(session);
        Session sessionToExpose =
                (enforceNativeSession || isExposeNativeSession() ? session : createSessionProxy(session));
        T result = action.doInHibernate(sessionToExpose);
        flushIfNecessary(session, existingTransaction);
        return result;
    }
    catch (HibernateException ex) {
        throw convertHibernateAccessException(ex);
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw convertJdbcAccessException(ex);
    }
    catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        // Callback code threw application exception...
        throw ex;
    }
    finally {
        if (existingTransaction) {
            logger.debug("Not closing pre-bound Hibernate Session after HibernateTemplate");
            disableFilters(session);
            if (previousFlushMode != null) {
                session.setFlushMode(previousFlushMode);
            }
        }
        else {
            // Never use deferred close for an explicitly new Session.
            if (isAlwaysUseNewSession()) {
                SessionFactoryUtils.closeSession(session);
            }
            else {
                SessionFactoryUtils.closeSessionOrRegisterDeferredClose(session, getSessionFactory());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The **org.springframework.orm.hibernate4** package still has the **SessionFactoryUtils** class but the **closeSessionOrRegisterDeferredClose** method is removed.

**Questions**:

I would like to know:

1) in which cases **Hibernate 3** will defer to close a session?

2) Do I still need to do the defer close if I use **Hibernate 4** sessions and classes in **org.springframework.orm.hibernate4**?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate does not close sessions.  It's up to the caller to close sessions.  In this case the caller is spring, and that depends on how you've setup your transaction management.

Spring will close sessions when your transaction commits, or optionally (if you're configured right) when a web request completes.

If you don't have any transaction management setup, the template will close the session as soon as it executes the callback you've passed to it.

What you're seeing with the HolderMap is part of that transaction management.

PS:  `HibernateTemplat`e went away in the hibernate4 package, but has made a comback in spring 4.  The preferred way of doing hibernate 4 in spring 3 is to use `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`, and let spring's transaction support manage the opening and closing of sessions.  IMHO, this was a huge mistake when they did it, but at least they've backtracked on it.

Comment: Maybe you could make the answer less opinionated? I think for instance that you shouldn't use the `HibernateTemplate` anymore as the case for it really doesn't exist anymore (as of Hiberate 3.0.1 with the introduction of the `CurrentSessionContext` the template was more or less a workaround for not having that and for hibernate2 it provided valuable exception translation. All of them can now be addressed in better ways, leading to a cleaner application i.e. less dependencies on the Spring API's.

Comment: i offered 1 line of opinion.  the fact that they brought HibernateTemplate back in spring 4 speaks to the fact that people wanted it.

Comment: It was reintroduced as a migration option and is also a minified version of the previous `HibernateTemplate` acting as a simple wrapper around `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession`.

Comment: Thanks guys and I didn't notice spring 4 brings the HibernateTemplate back. But if I stick with Spring 3, is there any replacement for the spring hibernate 3 method closeSessionOrRegisterDeferredClose? Or I don't need to do the deferred closing if use Hibernate 4 session?